# Absolute positioning of arrow

Tags: positioning, tikz-styles

I'm trying to put an arrow on the right of the text rectangles, but it doesn't work. Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass[compress,blue]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\definecolor{azure}{RGB}{74,100,217}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, fit, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts, shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{product size/.style={minimum width=1cm, 
    minimum height=1cm,
    text height=1ex,
  },
  product/.style={
    draw,signal, 
    signal to=east, 
    signal from=west,
    product size,
    fill=azure,
    draw=gray!50!white,
    text=white,
 },
}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{test...}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (1-t) at (10,12.2) [draw, minimum width=6cm,minimum height=1.2cm, text width=5.8cm, inner sep = 1pt] {She sells seashells by the seashore,};
\node (2-t) at (10,10.5) [draw, minimum width=6cm,minimum height=1.2cm, text width=5.8cm] {shells she sells are sure seashells,};
\node (3-t) at (10,8.7) [draw, minimum width=6cm,minimum height=1.2cm, text width=5.8cm] {so if she sells shells on the seashore,};
\node (4-t) at (10,6.9) [draw, minimum width=6cm,minimum height=1.2cm, text width=5.8cm] {I am sure she sells seashore shells.};

\node[product] (map) at (10, 12) {Input};

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

How can I position the arrow?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following solution:

```
\documentclass[compress,blue]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\definecolor{azure}{RGB}{74,100,217}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains, positioning, shapes}

\tikzset{product size/.style={minimum width=1cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    text height=1ex,
  },
  product/.style={
    draw,signal,
    signal to=east,
    signal from=west,
    product size,
    fill=azure,
    draw=gray!50!white,
    text=white,
 },
}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{test...}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 3mm and 10 mm,
   start chain = going below, 
    box/.style = {draw, minimum height=1.2 cm, text width=5.9cm, 
                  on chain}
                        ]

\node (1-t) [box] {She sells seashells by the seashore,};
\node (2-t) [box] {shells she sells are sure seashells,};
\node (3-t) [box] {so if she sells shells on the seashore,};
\node (4-t) [box] {I am sure she sells seashore shells.};
%
\node[product, right=of $(1-t.east)!0.5!(4-t.east)$] (map) {Input};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

I try to slightly optimize your code with use of two TikZ libraries: `calc`, `\chains` and `positioning`. The obtained result is:

[image]